# convergence of characteristic functions of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Q) If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for $1\leq n\leq \infty$, $X_n\implies X_{\infty}$ and $Y_n\implies Y_{\infty}$, then show that $X_n+Y_n \implies X+Y$.

$X_n\implies X$ if and only if $\phi_{X_n}(t)\to \phi_{X_{\infty}}(t)$, where $\phi$ is the characteristic function and since $X_n$ is independent of $Y_n$, $\phi_{X_n+Y_n}(t)=\phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)$ and so

$$\phi_{X_n}(t)\phi_{Y_n}(t)\to \phi_{X_{\infty}}(t)\phi_{Y_{\infty}}(t)\stackrel{?}{=}\phi_{X+Y}(t)$$

May I know why the last equality holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have is $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$, without the additional assumption that $X,Y$ are independent, then that last equality is false.

For instance, you could have $Z_1, Z_2$ be two independent standard normal random variables with $X_n = Z_1$ and $Y_n = Z_2$ while defining $X=Y=Z_1$

---

[Note that it's possible $X$ should instead be $X_\infty$ and similarly for $Y = Y_\infty,$ since these are independent, but this would need to be stated in the problem.]